# create an image from table

Tags: php, python, html, jpeg

I have following problem. I have txt file here : http://ch1zra.com/d2/runes.txt

I use PHP to loop throgh the file and generate this table : http://ch1zra.com/d2/runes.php

Table uses some basic styles and I like it that way.

txt file is generated and uploaded via python. I would like to create an image that looks like that table. Is there any way using python or PHP to do so ?

Any image format that is acceptable on the web is good, PNG being even quite welcome.
I've read somewhere that python reportlab can make styled tables with alignments and so on, so that could be a good start, but reportlab generates PDF. Of course, if that is just a step between it is also acceptable (if I could do the PDF > img conversion on my machine). ALso, IIRC every PDF contains a "screenshot" of each page for fast browsing, so that would also be cool.

All in all, I have this txt file and this HTML table that I want as image. If any1 can help that would be great :)

thanx in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I can only speak for PHP.

You could try to build the image by hand with PHP's image functions http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php

Or you could try executing a external script like: http://marginalhacks.com/Hacks/html2jpg/

Comment: I just managed to get my apache working, so I will give it a try in php.
thanx for directions :)

Comment: Damnit, PHP hurts me :)
Good thing is that I can premake my background and just layer over data with PHP, but the fact that I have to do it on every pageload makes me dislike it.
I keep my eye out for a python solution if possible 'cause in that case I could just make image locally and then upload it in a same manner as I do with my txt file using python.
(once you get to one method it's always a lot easier to stick with it than to learn new ways. Although learning new ways is good, I'd prefer a python solution for this problem)